# Recursive definition of multiplication

Tags: induction

I have the following function: 
$$
\begin{cases}
mul (a, 0) = 0&\mbox{if }n=0\\
mul (a, n) = mul (2a, \frac{n}{2})&\mbox{if }n\mbox{ is even}\\
mul (a, n) = mul (2a, \frac{n-1}{2}) + a&\mbox{if }n\mbox{ is odd}\\
\end{cases}
$$
It is clear that the function equals: $a * n$. a simple multiplication, but as I can prove by induction. Thank you.

Comment: You do not necessarily need induction to prove this. Here is a direct proof : if $n$ is even, $n = 2p$ ($p \in \mathbb{Z}$) then $\mathrm{mult}(2a,\frac{n}{2}) = 2a \times p = a \times 2p = a \times n = \mathrm{mult}(a,n)$. And if $n$ is odd, write $n = 2*p+1$ ($p \in \mathbb{Z}$). Then, $\mathrm{mult}(2a,\frac{n-1}{2})+a = (2a) \times p + a = a \times (2p+1) = a \times n = \mathrm{mult}(a,n)$.

Comment: It is possible, in fact giving values ​​is sufficient, it is clear but my question is how could a demonstration by induction applied to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint/here's one case: Suppose that $\mathrm{mul}(a,k) = ak$ for all $k \leq n$. If $n$ is odd, then by hypothesis $\mathrm{mul}(a,n+1) = \mathrm{mul}(2a,\tfrac{n+1}{2}) = 2a \tfrac{n+1}{2} = a(n+1)$.

Comment: Yes it is correct, thank you very much.